# How can I uniquely identify all of the calls to a function?

Tags: perl, perl-xs

I know that [`caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) will give me the file name and line number where a function was called, but how can I get the character or byte offset?  It is okay if I must drop down to XS for it (the function will probably wind up being XS anyway).

What I am trying to do is uniquely identify all of the calls to a function, so, if there is a better method than location in the source, I am open to other routes.

The basic intent is to make an `each` function that can safely iterate over the same hash.  Here is a pure Perl version that is similar to what I am thinking about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.012;
use warnings;
use Scalar::Util qw/refaddr/;

sub safe_each(\%) {
    my $h    = shift;
    my $key  = join "/", (caller)[1,2], refaddr $h;
    state %iter;

    unless (exists $iter{$key}) {
        $iter{$key} = [ keys %$h ];
    }

    unless (@{$iter{$key}}) {
        delete $iter{$key};
        return;
    }

    my $cur = shift @{$iter{$key}};

    return wantarray ? ($cur, $h->{$cur}) : $cur;
}

my %h = (a => 1, b => 2);
while (my ($k, $v) = safe_each %h) {
    say "$k => $v";
    while (my ($k, $v) = safe_each %h) {
        say "\t$k => $v";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you need to identify the calls for? And what counts as a unique call, for these purposes - for example, if I set `$f = \&myFunc`, then later write `$f->($param);`, that will call the function, even though there is no explicit mention of `myFunc`; what's more, exactly the same call site could call several different functions (if the value of `$f` changes while the program runs...)

Comment: The character or byte offset of what? The position of the function in the file? Or do you mean its memory address?

Comment: @psmears The point where it is invoked is the point where it is unique.  So if you say `my $f = \&func; func(); $f->(); $f->();` that is three unique calls.

Comment: @Ether position within the file, Needing to know the position in memory would be even more black magic than is needed or called for in this abomination.

Comment: Chas, you seem to do really crazy things with your code! :)

Comment: @Ether Hah, you obviously haven't seen Damian's code (http://search.cpan.org/~dconway) if you think my stuff is crazy.  This is for perl5i (http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/perl5i-v2.2.2/lib/perl5i.pm).  The idea is to try to fix `each` so that it is safe to use: http://github.com/schwern/perl5i/issues/issue/142

Comment: Perhaps you're approaching things the wrong way... e.g. how do other operators store local state, like the `..` operator?  I'd see how they accomplish it, and just do the same thing.  (or are you attempting to implement this just with pure perl, rather than delving into the internals?  I'd rather see `each` fixed with a core fix, rather than a hack on top.)

Comment: @Ether a core fix would require p5p to decide to break backwards compatibility, something they are loath to do.  By fixing it with a module we can have sane behavior without waiting for the multiple deprecation cycles p5p would require.  See the perl5i link for more information.

Comment: Good point about backwards compat! Although I can't imagine how anyone would be *relying* on that behaviour... *shudder*

Comment: I rely on the current `each` behavior in benchmark code. I have a hash of names to subroutines. I pull off one subroutine with `each` and execute it, I then use `each` in a loop to run all of the others and compare their results with the first one's. If any of them are different, then the code in the subroutines aren't equivalent and can't be benchmarked against each other. If `each` didn't have the existing behavior then I would run one of the subroutines twice.  Preferably, any new version of `each` would return an iterator that could passed into subsequent calls to duplicate this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The perl debugger loads all lines of the source files that it needs into the main symbol table under the entry

```
@::{"_<$path_to_file"}
```

This way when you reach a breakpoint at line *LINE* in file *FILE*, the debugger can display the line of code you are about to execute:

```
$::{"_<FILE"}[LINE]
```

But you could also use this information to compute the current character offset into your source file.

```
sub _get_offset_into_file {
    my ($file,$line) = @_;
    my *teh_codez = @::{"_<$file"};

    my $offset = 0;
    # the debugger spoofs line $teh_codez[0], so don't include it in offset calc
    $offset += length $_ for @teh_codez[1 .. $line-1];
    return $offset
}
```

You could either run your code under the debugger, or emulate what the debugger does and load the files into memory yourself (then you wouldn't have to use the same "_<" + filename convention, or even use the symbol table at all).

Sorry if this is an answer to a completely different question than the one you are asking.

Comment: I was trying to avoid loading the source files, I think I would rather let it misidentify the second call.

Comment: Oh, then just knowing the line number of the caller won't help anyway.